# Script to open Access database, run macro, and persist Access instance

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

I would like to have a script to:

1. Open an Access .accdb file
2. Run a macro within the database
3. Leave this open

I can very easily do the first two with the following VB script:

```
dim accessApp
set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.visible = true
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("C:\path.accdb")
accessApp.Run "myLinker"
```

But it immediately closes the Access database when the VBS execution finishes. I would like the instance to remain open independent of the script.

I am not forced to use VBScript for this but it definitely seems the easiest to actually invoke the macro to run.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to leave the application open after the script completes you need to set the `UserControl` property to `true`.

```
dim accessApp
set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.visible = true

accessApp.UserControl = true

accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("C:\path.accdb")
accessApp.Run "myLinker"
```

The `Visible` property is technically unnecessary when the `UserControl` property is true.  It will automatically be set.

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836033.aspx

Comment: Great, thanks. The description on the Application methods page is terribly vague and not useful with respect to its implication - `You can use the UserControl property to determine whether the current Microsoft Access application was started by the user or by another application with Automation, formerly called OLE Automation. Read/write Boolean` Guess that shouldn't surprise me from MSDN at this point...

Answer (score 2):

You could also just use a `.bat` or `.cmd` file and put this because MSACCESS has a command line switch for running a macro and unless that macro closes the database it will remain open for user control.

`START "" /MAX "PATH\TO\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\path.accdb" /x myLinker`