# Access/Excel VBA - Remove display alerts and messages

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a macro/vba in access that saves several excel workbooks after editing. However sometimes other users might be using one of the excel files in read/write mode.

The below message box appears, what i do is keep clicking no till the user  has finished using the Excel file

[image]

Once the file is free below message box appears , I click on 'read-write' and my code resumes from where it stopped (Image example)

[image]

Question - How do I get Access VBA or Excel VBA to click 'No' for me?

Note: I've used `Application.DisplayAlerts` and `DoCmd.SetWarnings` both default was `Yes`. (Or it might be me not implementing them correctly).

Code:

[Access/Excel VBA - Time delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174395/access-excel-vba-time-delay?noredirect=1#comment48456242_30174395)

```
Function RefreshExcelTables()

On Error GoTo Error

Dim ExcelApp As Object
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

ExcelApp.workbooks.Open "c:\test\Test_Sheet1.xlsb"
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.refreshall
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Close


ExcelApp.workbooks.Open "c:\test\Test_Sheet2.xlsb"
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.refreshall
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Close


ExcelApp.workbooks.Open "c:\test\Test_Sheet3.xlsb"
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.refreshall
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Close

Error:

If Err.Number = 1004 Then

call pause(5)

Resume

End If

Set ExcelApp = Nothing


End Function



Public Function Pause(intSeconds As Integer)

Dim dblStart As Double

If intSeconds > 0 Then

dblStart = Timer()

Do While Timer < dblStart + intSeconds

Loop

End If

End Function
```

Comment: What code causes displaying above messages? You have do improve your question.

Comment: Maciej Los - I've included my code

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the following option adjustment.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

More at: [DoCmd.SetWarnings Method (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837275.aspx) and [DoCmd.SetWarnings Method (Access Developer Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214103(v=office.12).aspx).

For the Excel.Application object you may have to use that instance's equivalent.

```
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false
```

The reference documentation for Excel's **DisplayAlerts** is at [Application.DisplayAlerts Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177478(v=office.12).aspx).

Comment: Plus there should be a test on whether the file is open by somefine else, I guess that was OP's main concern.

Comment: @user3819867 - Good point. That is going to require a bit more code than a single line. Knowing if Excel 2013 with its special way of handing application instances and application windows would be helpful on that front.

Comment: I'm just monitoring as it's going to be a helluva `While ... Wend` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Docmd.setwarnings False