# Open and run access macro from vb

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I use task scheduler in windows to trigger macros, I wanted to do this with an Access database accdb file format, however I keep on getting an error

> object required opencurrentdatabase("")

```
'Run Database
Dim ObjAccess, ObjDB
Set ObjAccess = CreateObject("Access.application")
objAccess.visible = false
Set ObjDB = ObjAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("filepath\filename.accdb", False) 'error occurs here
ObjDB.Application.Run "'Checklist.accdb'!cmdChkSelectAll_Click" 
ObjDB.Application.Run "'Checklist.accdb'!cmdGenerateAllLists_Click" 
ObjDB.Close False 
ObjAccess.Quit
Set ObjAccess = Nothing
```

Comment: I updated your tag to get rid of [access] (as this doesn't seem to be an access control issue) and add [ms-access] (because you say you are using MS Access).  However I don't think that is VB.Net code that you posted.  Are you sure it isn't VBA?

Comment: Must be VBScript. Edited tags. Are you trying to run a macro or VBA procedure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script to open Access database, run macro, and persist Access instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403424/script-to-open-access-database-run-macro-and-persist-access-instance)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me to run a VBA procedure in a general module and a macro:

```
Dim ObjAccess
Set ObjAccess = CreateObject("Access.application")
ObjAccess.visible = false
ObjAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("filepath\filename.accdb") 
ObjAccess.Run "Test6"
ObjAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro1" 
ObjAccess.Quit
Set ObjAccess = Nothing
```