# it is possible to call ms-Access function from outside

Tags: ms-access, automation, scripting, automationanywhere

I created a public function in an existing Access form and I`m trying to call it from outside the application.Very simple function just created for testing this.

```
Public Function test1(ByVal test1 As String)
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = False

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
End Function
```

I created the connection to it, on Automation Anywhere and I´m trying to call the function created.

Connection String im using:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source="$connection$";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="$pass$"
```

Tried doing this, without suceed

```
Select test1("test")
EXEC test1("test1")
EXECUTE test1("test1")
```

Also with simple '

**No way to do this on background so as suggested below I created a sub and called it from an VB Script**

```
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")  
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "RUTA ACCESS",,"CONTRASEÑA"
appAccess.UserControl = True
appAccess.Run "generarEtiqueta","numPropuesta","numExp","fileSavePath"   
appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
appAccess.Quit
```

generarEtiqueta is the sub, all the other are arguments

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script to open Access database, run macro, and persist Access instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403424/script-to-open-access-database-run-macro-and-persist-access-instance)

Comment: When I run the SQL command it doesn´t detect the method test1. Thats a good one but I´m trying to do all as background process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a module in access vba to use it in any form, or independent of form. The function can be called from outside as such:

```
Dim appAccess As New Access.Application 
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\My Documents\myDatabase.mdb") 
appAccess.Run "myDatabase.test1", "Pass your argument here"
```

Comment: Tried. Prefixing procedure with database name errors. Remove it and code works. But only for Sub, still can't figure out how to pass argument to Function.

Comment: Working fine. Opens the Access database but don`t seems like there is other way. Thank you

Comment: VBA code is run by the Access application, not by the database engine. So yes, Access must be running, with the database open. @Jonx

Answer (score 1):

Running code behind a form requires the form to be open. 
Example of a VBScript running a Sub and Function procedures in Access general module as well as a macro.

```
Dim ObjAccess
Set ObjAccess = CreateObject("Access.application")
ObjAccess.visible = false
ObjAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("filepath\filename.accdb") 
ObjAccess.Run("FunctionName")    'not finding a way to pass argument to Function
ObjAccess.Run "SubName", "argument" 'if Sub does not require argument then eliminate
ObjAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "MacroName" 
ObjAccess.Quit
Set ObjAccess = Nothing
```

I tested calling a Sub that issued a MsgBox and a Debug.Print. MsgBox works, Debug.Print does not.

Comment: I can declare it as Sub if that`s the problem. Also there is no way to work this on background without opening Access?